# Jquery keyup event not working when using classes

Tags: jquery, events, handler

I have an input field with a class of replyComment and I have a event handler that will determine if the enter key was pressed.

```
<input class="replyComment" placeholder="Enter Reply" type="text">
$('#replyComment').keyup(function (e) {
   alert(e.keyCode);
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Enter key was pressed.');
   }
});
```

The problem is that the event will not fire.
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` specifies an *id selector*, use a leading period (`.`) to specify a *class selector*:

```
$('.replyComment').keyup( ... )
```

Comment: I guarantee this selector will work for that class... do you add this element dynamically?

Comment: Adding from server-side code doesn't mean dynamically added to the DOM in this context.

Comment: So what happens is the page does an ajax call that goes to a ashx web service, this service returns the html of the comments, underneath each replt is that textbox. When the user clicks on enter I want it to do an event.

Comment: In that case then the code is put into the DOM on the client... so use `on` instead of binding to the event explicitly: `$('.replyComment').on('keyup', function(e) { });`

Answer (score 5):

As everyone has mentioned "#" refers to the elements denoted by id's.
Since the code you are using ->

```
<input class="replyComment" placeholder="Enter Reply" type="text">
```

is referring to class you need to access it via . selector. So ideally your code should be like

```
    $(".replyComment").keyup(function(){});
```

There may be cases when this also does not work if the element that has this class is not present in the DOM at the time of page load. If this is being introduced in your page after your page is loaded by some JS event or anything then you will have to bind it with the DOM using the **"on"** selector.

SO your code should be like

```
jQuery(document ).on( "keyup", ".replyComment", function(){ });
```

Hope this will be of any help

Happy Learning  :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use  (".") instead of ("#") in your code  like given below:

```
$('.replyComment').keyup(function (e) {
   alert(e.keyCode);
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Enter key was pressed.');
   }
});
```

Whenever you want to trigger an element than use "." instead of "#".
   ("#") always work with an id element.

Hope it will sort out your proble